# Entity Framework Doesn't Work Correctly ( Table Properties Not Loads with Intelligence )

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I added my database and table to the project with Ado.net EntityFramework wizard.
All necessary dll's loads up. But I can't see/reach my table's fields( fields like id - name - creationDate etc. ) Here is the code;

```
using CampaignManager.Database;

namespace CampaignManager.CampignController
{
    public class CampignController
    {
        public void UpdateCampaignWithCampaignId(int campaignId, Campaign campaign)
        {
            using (CampaignEntities db = new CampaignEntities())
            {
                //db.CampaignEntities.Where(item => item.)

                //Campaign gettingCampaign = (from entry in db.Campaign where entry. == campaignId select entries);
            }
        }
    ....
```

Here is the pic | EntityFramework - I can't see my table's coloumn names after dots - on questionmarks;
[image: EntityFramework - I can't see my table's coloumn names after dots - on questionmarks]

I already tried adding entity framework with nu-get manager. 
Close and reopen visual studio etc.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens when you uncomment the line and then press dot right after `item`?

Comment: Do you see the entity in generated model (after completing the wizard)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding using statements:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Campaign is the entity set? I'd expect it to be db.Campaigns, and the entity to be Campaign, by default?